# Hide child html elements if no innerHtml

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a c# function that would hide all child elements that had no innerhtml for the html control that was passed. Could someone point me in the right direction? Not real sure where to start on this one.

I'm using asp.net 4. Here's an example of my html structure..

```
<div id="officeInfo" runat="server">
    <h2><%= mlaLocationDTO.Name %></h2>
    <p><%= mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street1 %></p>
    <p><%= mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street2 %></p>
    <p>Tel:<%= mlaLocationDTO.Phone %></p>
    <p>Fax:<%= mlaLocationDTO.Fax %></p>
    <p>Email:<%= mlaLocationDTO.Email %></p>
    <a href="#">Get Directions</a>
    <a href="#">Submit Your Resume</a>
</div>
```

And my psuedo function...

```
protected void HideHtmlElementsWhenEmpty(Control element)
{
    foreach (Control c in element.Controls) maybe there's a better way than to use a loop
    {
        if(c.innerHtml != null) //not sure what to do here 
        {
            c.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need to encode your HTML output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output the HTML tags conditionally:

```
<%= String.IsNullOrEmpty(mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street1) 
    ? ""
    : "<p>" + mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street1 + "</p>" %>
```

Oh, and don't forget to properly encode your database output: Street1 might contain `<` or other HTML-unsuitable characters, and we don't want to risk any script injection...

```
<%= String.IsNullOrEmpty(mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street1)
    ? ""
    : "<p>" + Server.HtmlEncode(mlaLocationDTO.Address.Street1) + "</p>" %>
```

Comment: Thanks Heinzi. I was really hoping to streamline this a little more. Thats why I wanted to pass the parent element and just hide anything inside that had no content.  This solution works but is it possible to access the control itself to see if it has html?

Comment: @bflemi3: As far as I know, you can only access elements in code that have the `runat="sever"` attribute and some `ID="..."`. This won't help you for `<p>Tel: ...</p>`, though, since this will have `"Tel:"` as its `InnerHtml`, even if the telephone number is empty.